# how to prevent xss attack on angular applications

Tags: angular, xss, content-security-policy

I have this script in my response **<img src=x onerror="alert('attack')"** and in my .ts file i'm doing this
**document.getElementById("help").innerHTML=this.help;**
and it is executing in frontend and giving alert .. suggest how to stop this
using content-security-policy as

but no use.. any suggestions? please help

Comment: Quick suggestion: don't use `innerHTML`. Use angular bindings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use sanitizer, like this

```
constructor(private sanitizer: DomSanitizer) {
}    

public sanitize(value: string) {
    return this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustHtml(value);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For the onerror event attribute you'll need to rewrite using an event listener instead, preferably in a separate js file and not inline.

If it is unformatted text you aim to insert with innerHTML you should use textContent method instead as it is XSS safe. Another option is also to use DOMPurify to make it XSS safe.